# Are baseline text styles different than text styles used for Text input for React Native [iOS]?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a scenario where I'm trying to overlap a RN TextInput on top of a regular RN Text element. Basically, whatever text the user writes in the text input is mimicked to the text element underneath it.

Everything works great except when a user enters an emoji on iOS. In that case, the alignment is broken.

Here's an image without the emoji. (Red is Text element and Blue is TextInput element)
[image]

Here's an image with the emoji. (Red is Text element and Blue is TextInput element)
[image]

You can see that alignment changes for the Text element with the emoji. The text element moves up to accomodate the emoji.  It feels like the baseline line height for the TextInput and Text element is different.

How can I fix this issue?

Here's a link to my playground code. https://rnplay.org/apps/bswNmw

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an answer, but there's a workaround posted in this thread:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4457